# Is there a way to fix the View.ToggleDesigner Keystroke in VS 2019 for .Net 5?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, keyboard-shortcuts, .net-5, windows-forms-designer

I want to start developing Windows Form Applications using **.Net 5**.  One of the Keyboard commands that I have set up in Visual Studio 2019 and have used for pre-.Net 5 Windows Form Applications was to be able to toggle between the form designer and code by going into **Options>Environment>Keyboard** and assigning a keystroke to **View.ToggleDesigner**.  In all earlier versions of .NET in the same environment this keystroke works fine and it still works.  I have assigned Alt + Q to do this, but it gives me an error "ding" sound when I try to use it.  So I tried a different keystroke assignment but it still doesn't work.

I know that F7 and Shift+F7 will basically accomplish the same.  However, I would prefer using a toggle which is what I am used to and for me slightly faster.

Comment: This issue has been included and is [under consideration.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ToggleDesigner-key-binding-not-working-i/1296241?space=8&q=View.ToggleDesigner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resorted to using Ctrl+Tab to switch back and forth.  It functions just like the toggle keystroke.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

After my test.

The switching events are:

#### View.viewDesigner:

[image]

#### View.viewCode:

[image]

**Please try to modify and run.**

Comment: Again I already know about those two commands as I mentioned in my post.  I am looking to use the toggle.  I.e. one keystroke to switch back and forth.

Comment: This issue has been included and is [under consideration.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ToggleDesigner-key-binding-not-working-i/1296241?space=8&q=View.ToggleDesigner)